# Construction of skew-Hadamard matrix of order 292

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, combinatorial-designs, sage

I am currently looking into how to construct a **skew-Hadamard matrix** of order 292. Where can I find such construction?

According to multiple papers (e.g. [Koukouvinos and Stylianou - On skew-Hadamard matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2006.06.037) and [Seberry and Yamada - Amicable Hadamard matrices and amicable orthogonal designs](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=d42da0293057242ecdd9ce5654c7e4d6fbf5a10e))  this matrix has been constructed. However, none  of the papers I have found gives a reference to the actual construction that is being used to obtain it.

From what I have seen, it looks like the first paper which mentions its existence was published in 1978 ([Seberry - On skew Hadamard matrices](https://ro.uow.edu.au/infopapers/988)), with the first (*non-skew*) construction of an Hadamard matrix of order 292 being published in 1975 ([Spence - Skew-Hadamard Matrices of the Goethals–Seidel Type](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1975-066-9)).

---

The idea is to make constructions for various types of Hadamard matrices available in [SageMath](https://sagemath.org). We currently have quite a few already (and discovered gaps in literature along the way).

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, your [edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/439195/4) seems to be an answer (or a comment?), not part of the question.

Comment: @LSpice Full disclosure:  the poster is a student and a collaborator of mine.

Comment: From the proof of Prop. 3.4 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2043: "there is an infinite series of skew Hadamard matrices constructed by E. Spence [16] which contains such a matrix of order 4·73." The reference points to the paper cited in OP's question.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman in [16] there is a construction of a Hadamard matrix of order 292, but it's not skew-symmetric (and it is not claimed there in [16]  to be so, either).

Comment: @SteveHuntsman - Djokovic acknowledged that his reference to [16] was not correct - but sent us his own construction that fills the gap (for 292).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Nice!

Comment: Similar question for order 756 now posted by OP, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441321/how-to-construct-a-skew-hadamard-matrix-of-order-756

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The skew Hadamard matrix of order 292 can be constructed from skew supplementary difference sets (kindly supplied to us by Prof. Djokovic). This same construction is used, for example, in [Djokovic - Skew-Hadamard Matrices of Orders 436,580, and 988 Exist](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1973).

An implementation of this can now be found in [SageMath](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/34848).

Note that $H=\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,55,37\}$ is the order 9 subgroup of $Z_{73}$, and let
$$
J_1 = \{5,9,11,25\}\\
J_2 = \{11,13,17,25\}\\
J_3 = \{5,9,13,17\}\\
J_4 = \{1,3,13\}\\
$$

Then, we can obtain supplementary difference sets $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ with parameters $(73; 36,36,36,28; 63)$ and with block $X_1$ skew as follows:
$$
X_1 = \bigcup_{x\in J_1} xH\\
X_2 = \bigcup_{x\in J_2} xH\\
X_3 = \bigcup_{x\in J_3} xH\\
X_4 = \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{x\in J_4} xH\\
$$

From each set $X_i$, let $a_i = (a_{i,0}, a_{i,1},...,a_{i,72})$ be the {±1}-row vector such that $a_{i,j} = −1$ *iff* $j \in X_i$.

Then, we can construct four circulant matrices $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ where $a_i$ is the first row of $A_i$. We have that $A_1$ is skew, and by plugging them in the Goethals-Seidel array we obtain a skew Hadamard matrix of order **292**:
$$
H = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
    A_1 & A_2R & A_3R & A_4R \\
    -A_2R & A_1 & -A_4^TR & A_3^TR \\
    -A_3R & A_4^TR & A_1 & -A_2^TR \\
    -A_4R & -A_3^TR & A_2^TR & A_1
    \end{array}\right)
$$

Here $R$ denotes the matrix having ones on the back-diagonal and all other entries zero.